# Code review - Optimization & reduce redundancy

Tags: php, operators

For some purpose, i'm trying to create a helper class, and trying to make the cleanest code as possible.

What i'd like to know is : Do you have an idea how to compare variables stricly or not depending on a condition ?

Exemple :

```
// [...]
if ($strict) {
    return ($var > $test);
} else {
    return ($var >= $test);
}
```

Is there a proper or shorter way to achieve this ?

You will probably say that a short test like this is not a real pain, but, i simplified it for StackOverflow. My conditions are much biggest but as they are really similar except the operator, i really ask myself of how to achieve it.

Thank for help ;)

Comment: Ternary operator would be shorter... but a bit harder to read `return $strict ? ($var > $test) : ($var >= $test);`

Comment: That's a possibility, but i'm looking for more concise if it exists :p

Comment: Something like `return $var ($strict ? > : >=)  $test;` would be perfect :)